# Get child class called method name with parameters in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one class, let's say base class with constructor and one derived class, inheriting that base class as following

```
class base {
    constructor() {
       // Here I need classname, methodname and arguments. i.e. "derived, methodToBeCalled and 5"
    }
}

class derived extends base {
    methodToBeCalled(paramA: number) {
       
    }
}

new derived().methodToBeCalled(5)
```

As shown in above code, I need class name method name and method arguments in base class (I have mentioned constructor, but fine if there is alternative common way through which I can get these details)

Is this possible using Typescript? (or lets say Javascript...!!!)

Comment: Have you tried out whether it's possible?

Comment: The base class must not know anything about the classes that extend it.

Comment: Just make a method called `methodToBeCalled` in your base that acts like a dummy, other languages have something called abstract methods, and this would be pretty similiar.. And then you can just override it in your derived.  Seen as your using Typescript, interface's might even be a better fit, but you might be best explaining what problem your trying to solve.  Or even a mix of generic's would help too.

Comment: The big question is: Why do you need that? This might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), i.e. you are trying to solve one problem, think that you have a solution, but get stuck on that solution and want to get help on that. So what is your primary problem that led you to this situation?

Comment: @md2perpe. basically, I want to make an ajax call by intermediating all methods of class, based on called method.

Comment: @AnonymousCreator  `intermediating all methods`   Do you mean you want to wrap all the methods inside another function,.  eg:  If you have a method called `X` in the decedent,  and you then called X,  the Base could do something first and, maybe console logging `running X` as a simple example.?

Comment: I think you want [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) maybe?

Comment: @Evert. Exactly something like that. I will try this in couple of days as I am not in my workplace for few days. Till then you can add answer if you want that can solve my problem using Proxy. But yes, from what I have read from link of your comment, it can solve my problem.

Comment: I might be too lazy for a whole answer.

Comment: ok. np. I'll add if no one in couple of days. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use getOwnPropertyNames, you can call this on the derived class to work out what function are derived, and then wrap them inside another function, inside this function you can then use call to pass the args down to the derived.

Below is a simple example..

```js
class base {
    constructor() {
      const baseMethods = new Set(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(base.prototype));
      for (const method of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))) {
        if (!baseMethods.has(method)) {
          this[method] = (...args) => {
            console.log('Before: ' + method + ' with params', args);

            this.constructor.prototype[method].call(this, ...args);
            console.log('After: ' + method);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    thisIsNotWrapped() {
      console.log('This should not be wrapped');
    }
}

class derived extends base {
    methodToBeCalled(paramA) {
       console.log(`paramA = ${paramA}`);
    }
    anotherMethod(paramB) {
       console.log(`paramA = ${paramB}`);
    }
}

var x = new derived();
x.methodToBeCalled(123);
x.anotherMethod('Hello');
x.thisIsNotWrapped();
```

Comment: you guys are genius. I haven't verified yet, but logic seems to be outstanding.

Comment: you also solved one other problem as well which I didn't mention in question. That, I also wanted to omit actual derived class implementation. And for that I just will have to remove one line from your code. and I will get all I needed.

Comment: You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` instead of `this.__proto__` as well.

Comment: This solution can probably be made into a [class decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) (in Typescript) instead of having a base class.

Comment: @FelixKling  Yes, that would be cleaner, I'll update.  I thought there was a better way than __proto__ but couldn't remember..   Don't use classes as much these days, I seem to be using interfaces more often,

Comment: @md2perpe  Yes, that would be a very clean solution,..  Shame SO doesn't do TS Snippets, instead of having to create TS playground..